# Java String contains two-sided

Tags: java, string, lambda, contains, method-invocation

I created the following lambda to represent a BiPredicate.

```
(s1, s2) -> s1.getArtist().contains(s2.getArtist()) || s2.getArtist().contains(s1.getArtist())
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to make this more concise, maybe by using a method invocation or something else. I would prefer not to create extra variables and keep it a one-liner, but I am still open for other solutions if they make sense.

Comment: I don't see any need for improvement here.

Comment: What's the problem with this so that you want to improve it? Of course you could provide/use a method that checks if either string contains the other and call it but besides that? Hint for writing a method: you could first check which of those strings is the longer and then just check `longer.contains(shorter)` as it can't be the other way round - and if both are of equal length then just choose one to be "longer". Note that this would probably not make much of a difference unless you have _really_ long artist names.

Answer (score 0):

Some example of a 'faster' one - I picked special Strings to test, because java `contains` method already checks the length, which makes this approach and your approach basically the same if Strings differ in length (one `contains` is cut basically immediately after checking that first argument has shorter length). Also, since `contains` shortcuts after it finds that it cannot be true anymore, I made them differ only at the end. They are both really long Strings, you won't possibly encounter such Strings in your real world.

This approach is 2 times faster, because your is making a full check twice and this only once, but the difference is negligible, in a real benchmark it would be even smaller. And the Strings are cherry picked for the difference to be the biggest possible, so...

In conclusion: it's fine as it is if you want, but actually to me this version looks cleaner.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String a = "";
  String b = "";

  Random random = new Random();
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(119999999);

  for(long i = 0; i < 119999999; i++)
    builder.append((char) random.nextInt());

  a = builder.toString() + "zzzzzzzzz";
  b = a.substring(0, a.length() - 9) + "dsadsasda";

  Instant start = Instant.now();

  boolean test = a.length() > b.length() ? a.contains(b) : b.contains(a);
  //boolean test = a.contains(b) || b.contains(a);

  if(test)
    System.out.println("OK");

  System.out.println(Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis());
}
```